# Kivy Canvas Alpha Issue

Tags: canvas, kivy, alpha

I noticed when drawing textures (using Rectangle prims) to multiple widgets' canvas, some widgets become partially transparent, allowing the image behind to show through.

Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this behaviour, can you provide a minimal runnable example?

Comment: There's no specific code.  My app is broken down like this...  1 widget class represents the game world.  Every other widget gets added and  removed from this one widget.  A scrollview is created to hold the game world widget.  I have widget classes in other modules that represent the objects of the game world.  Each object class has it's own set of widgets that render an image from it's canvas.  Each image is loaed with the io.BytesIO method and converted to a texture, then drawn to a Rectangle prim of canvas as texture=bytesimage.

Comment: When I run my app, some png images are completely transparent while others are see through.  I have a module that resizes every widget when I scale up the window and when I do enlarge the window, the transparent rending of images seems to shuffle.  Some widgets that were not see through becomes see through while others that were see through stop being see through.  Kivy 1.9.0

Comment: Let me add, I don't use kv files, just python.

Comment: Seems like it has something to do with multiple rgba images laying on top of each other or overlapping.

Comment: I made a small change...  Instead of calling clear() on the canvas and using 'add' to place graphics back, I changed to just calling ask_update().  The only thing that did is stop the shuffling of transparencies when the window resizes.  I still have crazy visuals, for example...  Lets say a scene has a background of an office.

Comment: There's a widget that draws a pen-pusher to the screen and another widget that draws a desk in front of the pen-pusher.  Why is it the pen-pusher is semi-transparent to where I can see him through the desk (but the desk isn't semi transparent) and the background shows through him?  That is what I'm seeing with my graphics.  This didn't happen until I moved all graphics from widget backgrounds to the widget canvas.

Comment: You can see here, the control panel is almost completely transparent and that image is a solid image....  ??      http://imgbox.com/gO1kLlK2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out somebody involved in kivy development broke a mod/dll which deals with rgba while using a widget's background properties with an image.  Canvas is now the only reliable way to draw graphics with kivy.  Don't let desktop/laptop visuals fool you. You won't see the issue until you run your app with kivy launcher or build it into an apk.

Tested on Android (not ios).