# Opacity auto increase when resize the widget smaller to a specific amount in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am having an issue with the opacity when applying it in a widget and then resizing it smaller to a specific amount.

This is the original stance when the opacity at .5

[image]

Then you resize it smaller and when it reaches the point, its opacity starts to increase from the middle line like this (the same happen when you resize it vertically)

[image]

I have read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823494/kivy-canvas-alpha-issue) and wonder if mine is the same problem that one. Which mean this bug will not appear when you deploy it on Mobile with Buildozer?

Here its simple code:

```
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV_CODE = '''
#:import Label kivy.uix.label.Label
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

Button:
    text: "Cheese"
    opacity: .5
    size_hint: None, None
    size: Window.width/5, Window.height/5
    
'''

root = Builder.load_string(KV_CODE)

runTouchApp(root)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button` widget uses a `BorderImage` (I am not sure of its purpose), but that is what is causing the odd behavior. You can essentially eliminate the `BorderImage` by adding `border: 0,0,0,0` to your `KV_CODE`, like this:

```
Button:
    text: "Cheese"
    opacity: .5
    border: 0,0,0,0
    size_hint: None, None
    size: Window.width/5, Window.height/5
```

Comment: The border seems to be blurry after doing that, setting the value higher like 5,5,5,5 seem to fix that but also increases the value to trigger the "rising opacity" a little bit, but it's just enough since I don't need to resize it to a single point. Appreciate your help.